# If statement in android is not working

Tags: android, if-statement, toast

In my code there is following code...

```
if (true) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
```

When I run the application nothing is displayed...

But when I remove the above part & replace it with

```
Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

it works...

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why you use "if (true)"???

Comment: I also wondering about `Toast.makeText` work without `.show()` method!

Comment: @KarlKarlsom I guess for testing purposes -- to be sure that this branch will be called

Comment: That's not a good question title. If statement is working and if it didn't, people would have known before you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt any of your samples work, because you need to `show` the toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.show()` to display the Toast Message,

```
   if (true) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To display Toast :

```
Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to call show method , just see as follows,

```
   if (true) 
   {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
   {
           Toast.makeText(context, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For, the toast  You should use like below -

```
Toast.makeTest(context, "SomethingWhatever you Need to Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

without `.show()` it won't display the `Toast`